# Use maxflow to change edge capacities for higher max flow

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

Suppose we're given the max-flow and the corresponding residual graph, and edge capacities for an arbitrary digraph. We're also given said graph. Is there a way to check in linear time whether there exists a max-flow of at least $k$ by redistributing some of the edge capacities?

EDIT: the capacities need to stay integral

Comment: Where is the graph(s)?

Comment: Sorry I meant in general, not for a specific graph. Have changed the wording a bit

Comment: What sort of operations does "redistributing some of the edge capacities" allow? Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: Sure! Suppose we have 3 edges in which their capacities are {5, 5, 5}. Redistribution could include {15, 0, 0} or {1, 9, 5} etc. 
More concretely, say we had edges (s, u), (u, t), (s, t) with respective capacities 9, 4, 7. The max flow should be 11 here - edge (s, u) has capacity 9 but we put a flow of 4 on it. This saturates (u, t). Edge (s, t) has capacity 7 and we saturate that. 
Suppose we wish to check if a max flow of 12 could be achieved. This is true if we change the capacity of (s, u) to be 8, and (u, t) to be 5, keeping capacity of (s, t) as 7

Comment: Can we just take the shortest path from $s$ to $t$, and split the total capacity equally along this path ? In your example, you can achieve a max flow of 20 by moving all the capacities on $(s, t)$.